# How to debug a program hanging when launched?

Tags: software-installation, debugging, slackware

I've upgraded my Slackware 14.2 install and Scribus stopped working : when I launch it in a terminal, it just hangs, nothing happen — even when just querying help or version (`scribus -h` or `scribus -v`).

I don't really know where to start debugging this issue and I figure it would actually be the same whatever the software, hence the generic question : **how to debug a program hanging when launched ?**

As far as my particular case is concerned, I tried two different versions (slonly & slacky), with the same result, `ldd /usr/bin/scribus` doesn't show any missing symbols (in which case I would have expected a crash anyway, not a freeze ?), and removing `~/.scribus/` didn't help.

Comment: Are you familiar with `strace`?

Comment: @tk421 I know it exists, probably launched it once or twice long ago, but I cannot say I'm familiar with it.  I'll check it, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Following tk421's suggestion in comments, I launched Scribus under `strace` :

```
$ strace scribus
```

and it hanged on (if I recall correctly)

```
read(9, "We don't accept clients while"..., 64) = 64
```

I noticed the same issue on another program, with the very same result under `strace`.

Googling *"We don't accept clients while"* lead to [xfsm-manager.c](https://github.com/Distrotech/xfce4-session/blob/master/xfce4-session/xfsm-manager.c) :

```
        *error = "We don't accept clients while in CheckPoint/Shutdown state!";
```

which lead me to think XFCE might have been in a wrong state after a double attempt to suspend to disk yesterday, so I decided to reboot my computer.

After a reboot both Scribus and the other program work.